# Vaadin filter table containing checkbox components

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a table component in vaadin 6 , which has check boxes in it. How can I apply filtering to CheckBox component added in the table? I had previously done filtering in vaadin table component which had plain String as data. The CheckBoxes I added to the vaadin table have captions and I want to filter those checkboxes on the basis of their caption. Hopefully you got my point. So, I need help in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin 6 has own sorting methods in VScrollTable.java file. It sorts basic classes for example String, Integer, Date etc. Of course you can write your own table which has own sort methods but this can be get lots of time. You can search an addon for this.

May be this works for you: https://vaadin.com/en_GB/directory#addon/filteringtable:vaadin